# Contact the Field button when there are two buttons

Tags: javascript

I have a problem.
I want to build a home page with two fields: username and password, and then click the OK button.
Under this button, there is a button clicking on Sign
How do I associate the fields of an existing user button and not to button of registration?

Comment: can you provide proof of concept exactly what you are doing ....

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>login details</legend>
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="username">user name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control requiredField signIn" id="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control requiredField signIn" id="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default butt" name="submitButton" value="signIn">OK</button>
        </div>  
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Sign in</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Account Number:</label>
            <input type="password" name="account" class="form-control requiredField regi" id="account">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default butt" name="submitButton" value="regi">Registration</button>
        </div>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

//function registration_submit(){

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $(".error").remove();
    var hasError = false;

    if (Request.Form("submitButton":("signIn"){
    $(this).each(function(){
        if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == ''){
            hasError = true;
            var labelText = $(this).prev("label").text();
            var n = labelText.lastIndexOf(":");
            labelText = labelText.slice(0,n);
            $(this).parent().append('<span class="error"> you must fill ' + labelText + '</span>');
            console.log('the value of hasError is' + hasError);
            }

        });

    }
    else{
    $(".regi").each(function(){
        if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == ''){
            hasError = true;
            $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">you must fill Account Number</span>');
            console.log('the value of hasError is' + hasError);
        }           
    });
    }

    if(!hasError){
        $(this).submit();
    }

    return false;
});
```

});